# Cannot change keyboard layout in Qt Creator

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-13.10

I cannot change keyboard layout in Qt Creator 3.0 (build with Qt 5.2). This means that when I start typing in english I cannot continue typing, say, in russian by Shift+Alt combination.

In another application (e.g. Firefox) combination works.

Using: Ubuntu 13.10.

What can I do to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: same problem. ubuntu 17.04

Comment: I don´t know if this answer is the same for the op problem or even if is relevant anymore. but nowadays running QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland qtcreator solved a similar problem for me.